# How to handle error in JSON data has incorrect is node

Tags: json, scala, parsing, error-handling

I'm expecting following json format:

```
'{
  "teamId" : 9,
  "teamMembers" : [ {
    "userId" : 1000
  }, {
    "userId" : 2000
  }]
}'
```

If I test my code with following format:-

```
'{
  "teaXmId" : 9,
  "teamMembers" : [ {
    "usXerId" : 1000
  }, {
    "userXId" : 2000
  }]
}'
```

I'm parsing json value as follows:-

```
val userId = (request.body \\ "userId" )
val teamId = (request.body \ "teamId")
val list = userId.toList
list.foreach( x => Logger.info("x val: "+x)
```

It doesn't throw any error to handle. Code execution goes one. Later if I try to use teamId or userId, of course it doesn't work then.

So how to check whether parsing was done correctly or stop execution right away and notify user to provide correct json format

Comment: It's hard to help when you don't even mention which json library you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a value is not found when using `\`, then the result will be of type `JsUndefined(msg)`.  You can throw an error immediately by making sure you have the type you expect:

```
 val teamId = (request.body \ "teamId").as[Int]
```

or:

```
val JsNumber(teamId) = request.body \ "teamId" //teamId will be BigDecimal
```

When using `\\`, if nothing is found, then an empty `List` is returned, which makes sense.  If you want to throw an error when a certain key is not found on any object of an array, you might get the object that contains the list and proceed from there:

```
val teamMembers =  (request.body \"teamMembers").as[Seq[JsValue]]
```

or:

```
val JsObject(teamMembers) = request.body \ "teamMembers"
```

And then:

```
val userIds = teamMembers.map(v => (v \ "userId").as[Int])
```

Comment: You are **apparently** assuming he's using play json (right?). But he could just as well be using lift json (which also has the \\ and \ methods on its AST nodes, but no `as` method).

Comment: You're right -- I was assuming the json library.   This won't apply if he's using lift.  Good call.